# Discord ping vs plaintext, and how to respond to pings with my bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am creating a discord bot using discord.py that responds when certain users or roles are pinged, and I have run into an issue:

In my code I have the following: `if message.content == "@league": await message.channel.send("???")`

When no one has the league role, the text doesn't appear as highlighted, and the bot functions normally.

[image: bot works normally when no one has league role]

However, when I give myself the role, the text appears as highlighted, and the bot doesn't work.

[image: bot doesn't work as intended when users have league role]

Is there a way to check for pings using discord.py? Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Check the `message.role_mentions` attribute

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is get the role ID, and then when anyone has the role ID in a message it responds. Pinging the role counts as saying the ID. This also works with user ID's so if that's actually a user you're pinging, you can also just swap use the user ID. Here's an example.

```
@client.listen()
async def on_message(role):
    # add your id instead of the one provided.
    if "<@766730658235154439>" in message.lower.content():
        await ctx.send("???")
        await client.process_commands(role)
```

This should work, please comment if there is any issues.